# Conditional query fields in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongoose

1st Attempt ) I have a userSchema which contains personal Info of the user with parentId refrence. For a Find() query, I am passing a param named mobileVisibilty , which should exclude the mobileNo from the returned docs.

```
Person.find(queryFilter, { mobileNo: mobileVisibilty })
     .populate("parents.parentId")
     .exec()
     .then((docs) => {
       res.status(200).send(docs);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       res.status(500).json({
         error: err.message,
       });
     });
```

for mobileVisibily 0, It works as intended but for 1 , it excludes every other field. Intention is to have every other field with mobileNo.

2nd Attempt) As suggested I tried , $project conditional, but it behaves similar to 1st solution.

```
  Person.aggregate( [
    {
       $project: {
          "mobileNo": {
             $cond: {
                if: { $eq: [ 1, "mobileVisibility" ] },
                then: "$$REMOVE",
                else: "$mobileNo"
             }
          }
       }
    }
 ] )
```

3rd Attempt) Another logic I tried is by using conditionals if else, but it always runs the else block.

```
mobileVisibilty = req.query.vis;


if (mobileVisibility === 1) {
    Person.find(queryFilter)
      .populate("parents.parentId")
      .exec()
      .then((docs) => {
        res.status(200).send(docs);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err.message,
        });
      });
  } else {
    Person.find(queryFilter, { mobileNo: 0 })
      .populate("parents.parentId")
      .exec()
      .then((docs) => {
        res.status(200).send(docs);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err.message,
        });
      });
  }
```

4th Attempt) In Person Schema, I defined `mobileNo: { type: Number, default: 0, select: false },`

```
mobileVisibilty = req.query.vis;
console.log(mobileVisibilty ); //gives me correct value ie 0 or 1. But always if evaluates to true even for 0. 
if (mobileVisibilty ) {
    selectFilter = "";
} 
else selectFilter = " +mobileNo";

Person.find(queryFilter)
    .select(selectFilter)
```

One very stupid issue has cropped up in 3rd and 4th attempt . If I give values manually to mobileVisibilty ie 1 or 0, the solution works. But if I let it be defined through req.query , it always evaluates to true even for 0.

I have searched on stackoverflow but am not able to find a similar query.

Comment: Have you tried using `project`?

Comment: `find({...queryFilter, mobileNo: 0})`. the `find` method takes only one query object.

Comment: @ISAE, the second field is a projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, question was to conditionally hide a given field. So , first make a change in your Schema ie provide parameter `select :false`.

`mobileNo: { type: Number, default: 0, select: false },`

Then

```
mobileVisibilty = req.query.vis;
console.log(mobileVisibilty ); //gives me correct value ie 0 or 1.

if (mobileVisibilty == 1) { // I need to do type Casting since req.query.vis is a string. 
                            //I forgot that an empty string will evaluate to true.
    selectFilter = "";
} 
else selectFilter = " +mobileNo";

Person.find(queryFilter)
    .select(selectFilter)
```